# Install NVIDIA drivers through .deb files

Tags: drivers, nvidia, deb

So sometime ago I remember installing a NVIDIA driver through a .deb file instead of having the Terminal with .run files and it was a lot faster and the end result is the same. There was an PPA (at-least I think it was) on an official Ubuntu website that had the latest NVIDIA drivers in a .deb file... I have searched for hours trying to find it and to no avail... I know this isn't the typical question that gets asked here but I would really like to find it.

Answer (score 0):

Personally, I would never install drivers from PPA's. You can use "Find proprietary drivers" in Ubuntu system settings.

But if you really want to, you can try this: https://launchpad.net/~mamarley/+archive/ubuntu/nvidia

```
deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/mamarley/nvidia/ubuntu vivid main 
deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/mamarley/nvidia/ubuntu vivid main
```

In restricted Ubuntu repo

> http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/restricted/n/

you can find for example:

nvidia-graphics-drivers-experimental-310/   05-May-2015 12:28